# Do I need FIM on a single SharePoint 2010 Server?

Tags: 2010, people-picker, fim

I have installed a SharePoint 2010 on a single server.

It's a Windows Server 2008 Active Directory.

Do I need FIM installed?

I currently see both services as Disabled

[image]

And since I have an issue with people picker, I thought that I need to Enable these services.

Do I ?

Comment: What is your issue with people picker?

Comment: People picker isn't showing me any thing, and I am not sure if it has to do with FIM or not. Shooting in the dark unfortunately

Comment: You do not inherently need FIM to get people picker fields to work. I'd recommend trying a different path of troubleshooting.

Comment: thanks. I've tried the simple ones (actually posted here some) but as I didn't get answers, I tried to go FIM way :-/

Comment: Sadly, you're going to have to start working through the more advanced troubleshooting guides. The bright side is that you're going to learn a lot as you fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you see these issues when

1. apppool account doesn't have the rights to query AD
2. blocking LDAP or GC ports.

You can use a tool like NetMon or WireShark to see what happening in the requests.

As for FIM, its not required.  If your having picker issues I would clear this up before moving working your sync configuration.

Comment: changed the apppool to be the domain_farm_account